# Storing time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have data in the format of both "2013-01-17 18:46:47 -0800" and "1358477089"  ...I'm wondering what is the best way to store this in a mysql db, that allows me to select results within a certain month, week, day etc.. using mysql's own functions.

Currently my create table code is like this.. the "timestamp" needs changing.

visible

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: you DEFINITELY need to normalize that timestamp field and convert it to a native mysql datetime type. do that NOW, and then your actual problem will basically go away.

Comment: the `timestamp` varchar(32) NOT NULL, ...was just temp.. so I could do the php code to actually insert all the data.. I plan to delete the table and redo it all again using a proper formatted time column... just as soon as figure which time stuff will be converted to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a timestamp your field should be an "integer" not a varchar. This provides better perfomance (for example if you use an index for this column).

If you do not need to have dates before 1970 I would suggest to use a timestamp, not a datetime. It is easier to use.

PHP

```
$timestamp = date('U');
```

MySQL

```
INSERT INTO table SET timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to use MySQL built-in [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) type.

MySQL offers lots of function which will allow you to select results within a certain month, week, day, whatever you need.

See great list of functions here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

As **hek2mgl and other guys** mentioned, there is also **TIMESTAMP**.

*MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored.*

I preffer and advice you to use **DATETIME**.

Comment: Depends on what you'll do but of course +1. The timestamp type should also being mentioned

Comment: Yes, `timestamp` takes up half as much space (4 bytes vs 8 bytes), so it's worth considering if you do not need to store values outside of the years 1970 - 2037.